# Validation for Telephone filed with regular expression in react native

Tags: regex, reactjs, react-native

I want to restrict user from entering any special character in Input field apart from first character as `+` and total number of character not more than `15`. I want to check it using regular expression on `onChangeText` in react native. If user another `+` then it should restrict it.

I am using below expression which accepts only numbers but now I want it to accept first character as `+`.

```
export default (val) => {
  return val.replace(/\D+/g, '')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
export default (val) => {
  return val.replace(/^(\+)|\D/g, '$1')
}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2IVMGX/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(%5C%2B)%7C%5CD):

[image]

The regex matches and captures into Group 1 a `+` at the start of the string or any non-digit char in all other contexts and the match is replaced with the contents of Group 1. So, if there is a `+` at the start, it will be put back into the resulting string, else, it will be removed from the string.

Comment: How to restrict white space also ?

Comment: @technerd Could you please be more specific?

Comment: I want user to enter number like `+123456789012345`, but user not allowed to add white space.

Comment: @technerd `\D` matches whitespace and `.replace` will remove it.